# Regular expression pattern is no longer accepted by Chrome

Tags: forms, google-chrome, validation, input, pattern-matching

I have the following pattern attribute in form input:

```
pattern="^((https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\/\S*)?$"
```

It should do very basic level client-side URL verification and accept the following user inputs: `example.com`, `example-test.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://example.com` but not `examplecom` or `examplecom.`

About a year ago it worked fine with Chrome (and other modern browsers) but now it's not working any longer and gives a console error:

```
Pattern attribute value ^(https?://)?(www.)?(\[a-zA-Z0-9-\]+\[.\])+\[a-zA-Z\]{2,}(/\\S*)?$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(https?://)?(www.)?(\[a-zA-Z0-9-\]+\[.\])+\[a-zA-Z\]{2,}(/\\S)?$/v: Invalid character class\*\
```

I tried to change the pattern to make it work but I was only able to find a solution that accepts URLs without a hyphen (the pattern in the first input). It is weird that from some point Chrome started to struggle with character class syntax but the same code is working as expected with Firefox and Safari.

Does anyone know what causes the error with Chrome and how to get it to work like it does with Firefox?

Here is the code example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test pattern</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">

    <label>URL without hyphen (eg example.com)
        <br>
        <input
                pattern="^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(\w+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\/\S*)?$"
                class="text-input"
                required
                type="text"
        >
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>URL with hyphen (eg example-dash.com)
        <br>
        <input
                pattern="^((https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\/\S*)?$"
                class="text-input"
                required
                type="text"
        >
    </label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and now it's resolved.
The following characters no longer work in Chrome without escaping.

Some previously valid patterns are now errors, specifically those
with a character class including either an unescaped special
character or a double punctuator

```
pattern="[(]"
pattern="[)]"
pattern="[[]"
pattern="[{]"
pattern="[}]"
pattern="[/]"
pattern="[-]"
pattern="[|]"
pattern="[&&]"
pattern="[!!]"
pattern="[##]"
pattern="[$$]"
pattern="[%%]"
pattern="[**]"
pattern="[++]"
pattern="[,,]"
pattern="[..]"
pattern="[::]"
pattern="[;;]"
pattern="[<<]"
pattern="[==]"
pattern="[>>]"
pattern="[??]"
pattern="[@@]"
pattern="[``]"
pattern="[~~]"
pattern="[_^^]"
```

See below...
https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/7908